# Wordpress: How to translate custom Composer package with wp i18n?

Tags: wordpress, package, internationalization, composer-php, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a WP theme using Sage 10. I figured to create some `Composer` packages, hosted om GitHub, since I use multiple parts of code in multiple projects. To translate the theme I run `yarn translate` in the `CLI`, which runs `wp i18n`.

Now, this works fine for the theme, but how would I translate a package. So I don't have to re-translate it for each theme? How to store it in the package and for Wordpress to grab and use the translation?

-- Edit, as per request --

In my theme I use `Composer` as it is used by `Roots Sage 10`. In my composer.json I require my package with

```
"require": {
    "my-name/mypackage": "^1.0.0",
    ...
 },
```

My package and code are loaded by the autoloader of the theme. Now, in my theme I can translate the theme using `wp i18n`. The thing is, that I can translate the theme but not my vendor packages. So I would need to do it from the git of the package.

I guess this could be done, although I don't know how, yet. I suppose my composer package would become something like:

```
mypackage
 - src
   - languages
      - mypackage.pot
   - my-code.php
 - composer.json
 - init.php
```

Now, I would guess the should be a way to tell Wordpress there is a language translation inside the `/src/languages`. I would guess this would be done from the `composer.json` or the `init.php`.

But there is where my knowledge ends :)

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to Composer?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, thanks. I've added more details. It basically comes down to: " how to load an .mo file outside a theme or plugin"

Comment: That depends on how you load such a .mo file in other cases. Composer does not do that on its own, so that's something your application has to handle. Why not check how other plugins do this?

Comment: Plugins load it with `load_plugin_textdomain('my-domain', FALSE,'/languages/' );` But this returns a false. Even if the translated `nl_NL.mo` is in the folder and the `get_locale()` returns the right language. This makes me wonder if I can use `load_plugin_textdomain()` outside a theme or plugin. Since my package is not by definition a activatable plugin.

Comment: Alright, I thought I was not using the code right. `load_plugin_textdomain()` and `load_theme_textdomain()` where not working. So I thought I would needed a workaround. turns out that I need `load_textdomain()`...
`$mofile = get_locale() . '.mo';
    $loaded = load_textdomain( 'my-domain', __DIR__ . '/languages/' . $mofile );`

Thanks for the help Nico! You pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: As you haven't shared any code in your question, it's pretty difficult to see whether you are using it wrong

Comment: Valid point. At the moment of compiling this question I had no idea at all on how to approach this problem. No idea of the convention, hooks or functions to call. It was only through this conversation I got pointers. like `Why not check how other plugins do this?`. This gave me the insight to look at plugin localization. I did not think of it because I'm not making a plugin. And I only knew about placing translations in the theme root folder `/languages/`. Outside of that folder it wouldn't pick it up.